# Can I Hide a part of joomla link in source code?

Tags: joomla

Is is possible to hide the `href="...."` part of a `<link>` tag?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/nettt/plugins/system/jch_optimize/cache/jscss.php?f=019a87662ec9a3b8c890c566b8019f23-cache-plg_jch_optimize-652b9fac2d3cde50d0b5ec53b6e540d4&amp;type=css&amp;gz=gz&amp;d=30"/>
```

I want to hide

```
/nettt/plugins/system/jch_optimize/cache/jscss.php?f=019a87662ec9a3b8c890c566b8019f23-cache-plg_jch_optimize-652b9fac2d3cde50d0b5ec53b6e540d4&amp
```

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide" it?

Answer (score 2):

Would this affect functionality? If so, then it needs to be there (or the browser won't load the file and any dependency will fail).

If it does not (I'm not sure why you would want an empty link tag), you could do as @murali suggested and remove it using JavaScript (or use JavaScript to completely wipe the tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
var DOMlinks = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for(i=0;i<DOMlinks.length;i++){
DOMlinks[i].href = ""
}
```